# transforming a Series of lists into a structured DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, series

I have a pandas `Series`, where each entry is a `list`. I would like to transform it into a `DataFrame` in a particular way. Namely, I want the new `DataFrame` to have as many columns as there are elements in the longest `list` in the `Series`. This new `DataFrame` should be populated by the each row's list entries, and `np.nan`s where needed.

It is best seen in an example. Consider the following `Series`:

```
df = pd.Series([[1,2], [3,4,5], [6]]).transpose()
```

which looks like:

```
df

0       [1, 2]
1    [3, 4, 5]
2          [6]
```

The desired output is:

```
       0       1       2
0      1       2       np.nan
1      3       4       5
2      6       np.nan  np.nan
```

which I would like to acheive without looping if possible, as my actual series is very long.

Comment: Fastest is `df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist())`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Didn't know it's that simple

Comment: Sometimes you might be  able to formulate you input directly as 

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4,5], [6]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it correct, you just used `pd.Series` instead of `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4,5], [6]])
```